# Blinking layers HERE vector maps

Tags: javascript, here-api, heremaps

**Background:**

I'm working on integrating HERE maps with trucks restrictions to our web-based software solution.

**Issue:**

Halfway through the integration, I've noticed that when zooming-in/zooming-out the labels and truck restriction signs are blinking after reload. I've captured same behaviour in the example provided by HERE ([link](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/services/truck-routing-road-restrictions)) themselves.

[image]

As the issue occurs in their own examples I think it is safe to state that it's not my implementation problem.

I've seen (also in their examples), that when their vector tiles are integrated using mapbox.gl, the zoom-in/zoom-out becomes smooth, but I would prefer to use their own javascript library due to other advantages (like traffic incidents display, etc.).

**Question:**

Anyone has any ideas how could that be solved?

Comment: I not familiar with the here.com maps API, but I assume, by looking at there example you linked above, that you are out of luck her. Be inspecting the map itself I discovered it being a canvas element. Thus the map is drawn by means of JavaScript and I fear there is not much you can do about it. Unless there is some plugin mechanism which you can override the drawing routine with.

Comment: It isn't blinking, it is rendering in a new position...

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the effect and i understand what you mean. From what i understand (i have not worked with `HERE` maps before), while a user zoom in/out the re-rendering process is the one that produces that `single-flicker` of a point sometimes.

There are 2 JSFiddle examples [A](https://jsfiddle.net/y3nxego9/) and [B](https://jsfiddle.net/39zdbLoh/), you will spot a difference but i think the problem not eliminated.

Example Code

```
/**
 * A full list of available request parameters can be found in the Routing API documentation.
 * see:  http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing/topics/resource-calculate-route.html
 */
var routeRequestParams = {
      routingMode: 'fastest',
      transportMode: 'truck',
      trafficMode: 'enabled',
      origin: '40.7249546323,-74.0110042', // Manhattan
      destination: '40.7324386599,-74.0341396'
    },
    routes = new H.map.Group();

async function calculateRoutes(platform) {
  var router = await platform.getRoutingService(null, 8);

  // The blue route showing a simple truck route
  calculateRoute(router, routeRequestParams, {
    strokeColor: 'rgba(0, 128, 255, 0.7)',
    lineWidth: 10
  });

  // The green route showing a truck route with a trailer
  calculateRoute(router, Object.assign(routeRequestParams, {
    'truck[axleCount]': 4,
  }), {
    strokeColor: 'rgba(25, 150, 10, 0.7)',
    lineWidth: 7
  });

  // The violet route showing a truck route with a trailer
  calculateRoute(router, Object.assign(routeRequestParams, {
    'truck[axleCount]': 5,
    'truck[shippedHazardousGoods]': 'flammable'
  }), {
    strokeColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.7)',
    lineWidth: 5
  });
}

/**
 * Calculates and displays a route.
 * @param {Object} params The Routing API request parameters
 * @param {H.service.RoutingService} router The service stub for requesting the Routing API
 * @param {mapsjs.map.SpatialStyle.Options} style The style of the route to display on the map
 */
async function calculateRoute (router, params, style) {
  await router.calculateRoute(params, async function(result) {
    await addRouteShapeToMap(style, result.routes[0]);
  }, console.error);
}

/**
 * Boilerplate map initialization code starts below:
 */

// set up containers for the map  + panel
var mapContainer = document.getElementById('map');

// Step 1: initialize communication with the platform
// In your own code, replace variable window.apikey with your own apikey
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
  apikey: window.apikey
});

var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

// Step 2: initialize a map - this map is centered over Berlin
var map = new H.Map(mapContainer,
  // Set truck restriction layer as a base map
  defaultLayers.vector.normal.truck,{
  center: {lat: 40.745390, lng: -74.022917},
  zoom: 13.2,
  pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1
});
// add a resize listener to make sure that the map occupies the whole container
window.addEventListener('resize', async () => await map.getViewPort().resize());

// Step 3: make the map interactive
// MapEvents enables the event system
// Behavior implements default interactions for pan/zoom (also on mobile touch environments)
var behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map));

map.addObject(routes);

/**
 * Creates a H.map.Polyline from the shape of the route and adds it to the map.
 * @param {Object} route A route as received from the H.service.RoutingService
 */
function addRouteShapeToMap(style, route){
  route.sections.forEach(async (section) => {
    // decode LineString from the flexible polyline
    let linestring = await H.geo.LineString.fromFlexiblePolyline(section.polyline);

    // Create a polyline to display the route:
    let polyline = await new H.map.Polyline(linestring, {
      style: style
    });

    // Add the polyline to the map
    await routes.addObject(polyline);
    // And zoom to its bounding rectangle
    await map.getViewModel().setLookAtData({
      bounds: routes.getBoundingBox()
    });
  });
}

// Now use the map as required...
calculateRoutes (platform);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't a good solution for this. It is caused by the way that the page is rendered through the here api. I don't think its fixable.

Having said that you might be able to add some css that would fade in the elements so the transition is smoother.

So you would need to detect the current value of

```
zoom:
```

and if it changes you would want to trigger the css animation.

It will take a bit of work and won't be a perfect solution but its better than nothing.

Comment: I think the other guy answered it better though